# Are there any tools to migrate data from Nokia to iPhone?

Tags: ios, applications, migration

I'm new to Apple and I'm looking for tools that will allow my to backup my contacts and calendar and such on my Nokia X6 and move/restore them to my Apple iPhone. How is this possible?

Is there any interface for this? Any application that sends from Nokia by Bluetooth to iPhone? Or, like MS Outlook, to be a gateway for converts?

Is there any Java app or Symbian app compatible for Nokia?

Comment: Most cellular companies have a [Cellebrite](http://www.cellebrite.com/retail-products.html) device in their retail stores with about 100 cables to fit each and every phone on the planet and can effect a transfer for little or no cost for their subscribers. Also, I'm going to close this since it's not really asking about OS X or iOS and the various formats they import but instead focused on Nokia and Symbian.

Comment: you can focus on Nokia But i focused on iPhone.

Comment: The phone works with Exchange, google, iCloud and iTunes as well as contacts stored on a SIM. If you want to edit out the parts that are off topic, flag this for a review and reopen.

Comment: how about contacts ,  notes , calendar, tasks , ...

Answer (score 1):

You almost have given the answer yourself: you use an intermediate system ("gateway", as you name it) which is supported by both the Nokia and the iPhone. I don't know nothing about Nokia phones, but I think they are able tosync with Outlook or Google contacts/calendar. You sync your Nokia phone's contacts/calendar to the intermediate and then sync the contacts/calendar to your new iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

If you also have a mac computer iSync could be a way of synching contacts and calendars – depending on Mac OS version and Nokia model…

https://www.apple.com/support/isync/

Comment: Since iSync only ran on Mac OS 10.5 Leopard, it's not a very viable suggestion at this point except in a very narrow case. I suppose some might still have an old enough iPhone and Mac to work with iSync.